# I cant Display data in Xamarin Forms using WCF postgresql

Tags: postgresql, forms, wcf, xamarin, service

This is my code into the wcf servis

public DataSet SelectUserDetails()

```
    {
        npgsqlcon.......   
        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("Select * from RegistrationTable", con);
        NpgsqlDataAdapter sda = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return ds;
    }
```

And this is the xamarin forms code

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
ServiceReference1.Service1Client objService = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        showdata();
    }

    private async void showdata()
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = await objService.SelectUserDetailsAsync();
        liste.ItemsSource = (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ds.Tables[0];
        
        
    }
```

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBGgy.png)

Comment: does `ds.Tables[0]` contain data?  How are you binding the properties in your XAML?

Comment: Try to move the `showdata()` method into`OnAppearing()` method.